# Table header: diagbox line does not touch corner

Tags: tables, diagbox

Diagbox in table header does not touch corner of cell. Thank you for any help.

Here is the Minimal Working Example (MWE), and at bottom a picture of what that MWE is rendering:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]
    {
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.16\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.20\textwidth}|p{0.09\textwidth}|p{0.09\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.16\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \diagbox[width=7em, height=3em]{\thead{\textbf{Auteurs}}}
        {\thead{\textbf{Critères}}} & \thead{Environnement \\technologique} & \thead{Scénarisation \\pédagogique} & \thead{Interactions \\entre acteurs tiers} & \thead{Mode de \\livraison} & \thead{Analyse \\logicielle} & \thead{Conception \\logicielle} & \thead{Développement \\logiciel}\\
        \hline
        & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
        \hline
        \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{Oui} & \footnotesize{Oui} & \footnotesize{Oui} & \footnotesize{Non} & \footnotesize{Non} & \footnotesize{Non} & \footnotesize{Non}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{Comparaison.}
    \label{tab:comparaisonPatrons_3}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, setting the fontsize to `\footnotesize`, and replacing the`p{some width}` column qualifier with a plain `c`. I also loaded `fontenc` with option `T1`, to get accented letters:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering\footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
      \hline
      \bfseries\diagbox[width=\dimexpr 0.15\textwidth+2\tabcolsep\relax, height=0.98cm]{Auteurs}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{Critères}}
                      & \thead{Environnement\\technologique} & \thead{Scénarisation \\pédagogique} & \thead{Interactions \\entre acteurs tiers} & \thead{Mode de \\livraison} & \thead{Analyse \\logicielle} & \thead{Conception \\logicielle} & \thead{Développement \\logiciel}\\
      \hline
                      & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} \\
      \hline
      \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{Oui} & \footnotesize{Oui} & \footnotesize{Oui} & \footnotesize{Non} & \footnotesize{Non} & \footnotesize{Non} & \footnotesize{Non} \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  \caption{Comparaison.}
  \label{tab:comparaisonPatrons_3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The ampersands in `\thead{Environnement & & & & & & \\technologique}` should not be there, They cause error in compiling.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. It's an old trick from my editor. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has its own command `diagbox` which draws the rules with PGF/Tikz (hence, a perfect output). You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{18mm}*{7}{c}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=2pt]
\diagbox{\textbf{Auteurs}}{\textbf{Critères}}
   & \Block{}{Environnement\\technologique} 
   & \Block{}{Scénarisation\\ pédagogique} 
   & \Block{}{Interactions \\entre acteurs tiers} 
   & \Block{}{Mode de \\livraison} 
   & \Block{}{Analyse \\logicielle} 
   & \Block{}{Conception \\logicielle} 
   & \Block{}{Développement \\logiciel} \\
   \\
   & Oui & Oui & Oui & Non & Non & Non & Non \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Comparaison.}
\label{tab:comparaisonPatrons_3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]